# Missing [Number of records] Error Tableau Server

Tags: tableau-api

Directly within the Tableau Server (10.2) interface, I am receiving this error when I try to download the full data.

```
 {"ErrorType":"Unknown","RedirectUrl":null,"ErrorMessage":"No such column      
 [Number of Records].\n
 2017-07-25 03:07:10.897, (WXa13goAAAQAAEyAFWgAAAG@,0,1)"}

 Steps to recreate:
 1. Open viz in Server 
 2. Click Download
 3. Select Data
 4. Click Full Data Tab
```

Summary data is visible and downloadable. I am using the [Number of Records]  field in the viz but I can't imagine that it wouldn't function in server since it is Tableau generated.

I have tried in Firefox, Edge, and IE.

Comment: What type of data source (Oracle, MySql, etc.) are you connecting to and is it live or an extract?

Comment: It is an extract that is loaded onto Server as well.

Comment: SQL Server is original source for the extract

Comment: I've seen this happen once or twice before. It was due to a corrupt extract. Out of laziness, I took the brute force approach by opening the workbook in Desktop, removing the extract, then rebuilding it, and republishing.